# How to work printf inside?

Tags: c, casting, printf

I asked myself not once. And i do not understand for what it done?

For example:

**1. Code**

```
char a = 'h';
printf("%i", (int)a); /// Conversion 'a' to int, and again conversion to int by modifier %i. Right?
```

If I will be written so - you will say: it's wrong!

**2. Code**

```
printf("%i", a);
```

Why, it's wrong??? We convert 'a' to int type by modifier %i and output after.

In what difference between 1 and 2 codes?

P.S Why I can't output simple as in C ++ through 'cout' analogue?

Comment: `I asked himself`...what?

Comment: @SouravGhosh in the title =)

Comment: The `%i` is not a "conversion". It's an output format specifier, it tells `printf()` how to take a value of a certain type ( `int` in this case) and convert it to characters forming a textual representation of the value (decimal diigts, in this case).

Comment: @MaximPro - *"in the title"* I read it but I still have to second Souravs question.

Comment: @StoryTeller Because I have confusion in my head

Comment: I think "himself" --> "myself", inn'it?

Comment: @SouravGhosh omg, I am ashamed

Comment: @unwind: Actually `i` after the `%` is a conversion specifier according to the standard. The type is implied. `%i` is a conversion specification. But I'm not sure if OP might mean the cast, which is not just a conversion.

Answer (score 2):

A code like

```
 printf("%i", a);
```

is correct, because `printf()` is a variadic function and for its arguments, default argument promotion rule applies and `a` will be promoted to `int`, anyway.

A code like

```
 printf("%i", (int)a);
```

is also correct, but the cast is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: ok, if i replace int to float? `printf("%f", (float)a);` and `printf("%f", a);` difference?

Comment: Does it make sense to conversion the variable to the desired type if printf does everything for me?

Comment: @MaximPro In short, no. You don't need that explicit cast here. Read about default argument promotion rule, you'll understand the reason.

Comment: @MaximPro When the default promotions happens to do exactly what you want, the explicit conversion is not necessary, but it may be helpful to make the code more self-documenting. When the default promotions don't do what you want, then you do need to explicitly convert the type.